# Why won't this write to my text file in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying and searching for hours and everything is telling me to do exactly as I am doing, so why won't this code write to my text file? No errors are being thrown, just the data won't write

```
Dim newDay As Boolean = True
Dim attendance As StreamWriter
    If newDay = True Then
        Try
            attendance = File.AppendText("attendanceLog.txt")
            attendance.WriteLine(Date.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
            newDay = False
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("File access denied", "Error")
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: close the writer. i've never used VB but i think at end of try block it will be `attendance.Close()`

Comment: Your file name does not have a file path - is it creating another file in the bin directory that you haven't noticed?

Comment: I forgot to close it. Thank you, Zohaib

Comment: perhaps @Greg is right. try to add file path. `attendance = File.AppendText("D:\\attendanceLog.txt")` for example

Comment: I want the log in the default path, which may not work practically, but in the current situation, it's my best option

Comment: Always open file streams with a `Using` block. That way it’s closed automatically, even when an exception is thrown. Don’t `Close` manually.

Comment: @AlexHamilton Could you explain what *you* mean by "default path" please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `StreamWriter`, all you send will be put in a queue to avoid writing to the file everytime a new part needs to be appended (which is very inefficient with large files like logs).

To process that queue, simply call [`StreamWriter.Flush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But this is discouraged.
You should instead use [`StreamWriter.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the end, which does this automatically and then disposes the object from memory, too.

```
Dim newDay As Boolean = True
Dim attendance As StreamWriter
If newDay = True Then
    Try
        attendance = File.AppendText("attendanceLog.txt")
        attendance.WriteLine(Date.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
        attendance.Close()
        newDay = False
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("File access denied", "Error")
    End Try
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to but your file path

```
File.AppendText("c:\users\admin\document\attendanceLog.txt")  //for example
```

i think that will be work, or you can find the attendanceLog.txt on local project file ..